# Access output of a c++ code which is called in python with suprocess.check_output

Tags: c++, opencv, subprocess

I have a python code which is worked on images. for some performance reasons, I decided to use a C++ program which has a function that hasn't any input argument but its output is an image data in cv::mat format.

I want to access to this output data from my python code.

I call this c++ code using subprocess.check_output.

how can I access the image data from my python code?

this is part of my python's code:

```
        s1 = subprocess.check_output("g++ watermark.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -lm  -o out2;./out2",
                                     shell=True)

        print("TYPE ==> ", type(s1), " size : ", sys.getsizeof(s1))

        print(s1.decode("utf-8"))
```

and this is my c++ code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat watermark()
{
        cout << " This is a simple watermark !";
        Mat source_img, watermark_img;
        source_img = imread("source.jpg");
        watermark_img = imread("my_logo.png");

        int width = watermark_img.size().width;
        int height = watermark_img.size().height;
        int x_pos = rand() % (source_img.size().width - width - 10) + 10;
        int y_pos = rand() % (source_img.size().height - height - 10) + 10;

        cv::Rect pos = cv::Rect(x_pos, y_pos, width, height);
        double alpha = 0.5;

        addWeighted(source_img(pos), alpha, watermark_img, 1 - alpha, 0.0, source_img(pos));

        return source_img;
}


int main()
{
        Mat new_image = watermark();
        return 0;
}
```

I want to access to new_image data in main function.

when I run my python code, it is worked completely and I see this message: " This is a simple watermark !"

but I don't know how to access image data to use it in my python's code to show it.

Does anybody have any idea to help me?

Comment: It is a funny approach to build the C++ code when calling it from Python. Anyway, what about saving the output to a file in C++ and read it in Python?

Comment: @nielsen why it is funny? I don't want to save my output in a file because finally we have one write and read operation additionally. Actually my final aim is have a c++ code which accepts a byte aaray as its argument and after process it, return a byte array as its output.

Comment: Normally, you would compile the C++ code into an executable or DLL beforehand. It sounds like you would rather want a DLL. In that case you should btw. define a plain C (not C++) interface for the DLL and have a look at the `ctypes` library.